# Can't fix this error using OpenLayers v6.3.1 release

Tags: openlayers

I'm very new at using OpenLayers.  I really would like to test the consumption of a WFS xml file being returned from a REST call.  Using Openlayers v6.3.1 release:

https://openlayers.org/download/

I coded up Thomas Gratier's Block that works with a WFS xml file:

https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/5579a8831db6fa0f5641474e56739201

My code is exactly as is shown on that web page with the only exception being that I am using the URL provided in the mapserver.org site:

https://mapserver.org/input/vector/wfs.html

... That URL being:

> https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?
> SERVICE=WFS&
> VERSION=1.0.0&
> REQUEST=getfeature&
> TYPENAME=continents&
> MAXFEATURES=100

When I run this using npm, I keep getting this error:

> TileLayer.js:161 Uncaught TypeError: tileSource.getTileGridForProjection is not a function

As stated I'm really new at using the OpenLayers API.

Am I getting this error because of the mapserver.org URL I am using or is this a bug in the latetest version of OpenLayers?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60456973/4699904

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues if using the standalone demo you point:

- CORS. You need to set a proxy
- WFS version compared to the OpenLayers WFS parser. You need to call WFS 1.1.0 instead of 1.0.0 version

In the code, you need to replace `var url = ...` with the following

```js
    // Be careful, this cors proxy only useful for demo
    // not for production purpose! You need to use your own.
    var cors_proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
    var url = cors_proxy + 'https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?' +
              'SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=getfeature&' +
              'TYPENAME=continents&MAXFEATURES=100';
```

The error you met seems quite unrelated to both issues I highlight. From you mention of NPM, you are trying to use a standalone sample using NPM/Node whereas using them need to change the sample code quite a lot. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093964/why-examples-dont-work-a-struggle-with-imports/51110511#51110511

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  Can you please point me to where / how I can download and use the WFS 1.1.0 version of WFS?

Comment: You just need to change your WFS call to `VERSION=1.0.0` to `VERSION=1.1.0` in `url` variable. Already in my answer although not very visible due to long url in the sample (reformated to be more visible)

Comment: Disregard my previous posting.  I opened the package-lock.json in my Node project and I see that it is using WFS 1.1.0:


    "wfs": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/wfs/-/wfs-1.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-RsnYpJc60ZXTEMW6ir1dLHqyook=",
      "requires": {
        "async": "~2.4.0",
        "debug": "~2.6.8",
        "formatter": "~0.4.1",
        "request": "~2.81.0",
        "strip-bom": "~3.0.0",
        "underscore": "~1.8.3"
      },

Thank you

Comment: Not sure I understand. You don't need any package wfs in `package.json`. When you use Openlayers, you already have a WFS parser. With the code, Openlayers makes an http calls (using a standard called WFS). It returns an XML describing geometry and attributes. OpenLayers will parse the this XML and transform it to OpenLayers native feature(s).

Comment: Yes sir.  I did a "npm install WFS" because I interpreted what you stated  as that I needed to use WFS1.1.0.  Anyway I did not catch your posting where you redid the url with the "WFS...VERSION".. parameters until a few mins ago.  Thank you for that.  I tried that in the code an now at the line found in Thomas Gratier’s posting:
....vectorSource.on('change', e => {.....
I get this error:
TileLayer.js:161 Uncaught TypeError: tileSource.getTileGridForProjection is not a function
    at CanvasTileLayerRenderer.renderFrame (TileLayer.js:161).

The adventure continues... thx again..

Comment: A solution https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-wfs-parcel-iggls?file=/index.js Can't do more. Use Parcel (similar to webpack). You need to go to menu "File" then "Export to ZIP". After retrieving the zip, unzip in a directory. With command line, "cd" into the directory do `npm i`, `npm start` and open your browser to http://localhost:1234/ and you got a local working Openlayers demo

Comment: ThomasG77:  Thank you very much for your time and patience for creating that nice zip package.  The problem was a stupid error in my code  I had

Comment: ThomasG77:  Thank you very much for your time and patience for creating that nice zip package.  The problem was a stupid error in my code  I had
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
which of course s/have been:
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
So I guess that got the.."vectorSource.on('change' ..."  all angry.
So the generated map has 2 countries outlined.  Is that because of the
dataProjection and / or featureProjection parameters entered in the vectorSource.addFeatures code?

Comment: Not it's because there is a parameter `MAXFEATURES=100` in the url. So you get 100 features (too heavy to download). Most features are small so you don't see them well. Replace the url declarationwith this example `var url = cors_proxy + 'https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=getfeature&TYPENAME=continents&Filter=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>NA2DESC</PropertyName><Literal>France</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>';` Not on OpenLayers side but MapServer can use filter e.g https://www.mapserver.org/ogc/filter_encoding.html#table-of-contents